# Disk I/O with Monit under Linux

Tags: monit

I would setup some rules for Monit to alert when disk read / write rate reach specific values.

I'm trying to configure it using their exemples, like:

`check filesystem xxx with path /xxx/xxx
       if read rate > 90% then alert`

I tried many variant but i always get syntax problem when checking it with monit -t.

The first line is good and i can see the filesystem analytics in monit but the alert line always fail.

Someone have an idea about what i'm doing wrong and how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

---

Ok, i just found that this function was not implemented in the version i'm using. So now i'm trying to find a way to update this monit.

Comment: Post what you've already tried, and people might be able to suggest what you're doing wrong

Comment: Did you still need help to upgrade your version ?